# asp.net core 3.1 Writing to the response body is invalid for responses with status code 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, kestrel-http-server, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using asp.net 3.1 and Swagger (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) 5.4.1 to generate api documents. I have an api with `DELETE` method that deletes a resource and return `NoContent(204)` response like this:

```
    [HttpDelete("{id:guid}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteAsync(Guid id)
    {
        var existedEntity = await _discountCodePolicyRepository.GetAsync(id, HttpContext.RequestAborted);

        if (existedEntity == null)
            return NotFound();

        await _discountCodePolicyRepository.DeleteAsync(existedEntity, HttpContext.RequestAborted);

        return NoContent();
    }
```

It's works fine from swagger UI but when called from our clients (website), throw blow exception:

`` System.InvalidOperationException: Writing to the response body is invalid for responses with status code 204. Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol", in  ThrowWritingToResponseBodyNotSupported Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol", in  FirstWriteAsyncInternal Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol", in FirstWriteAsync Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol", in WritePipeAsync Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream", in WriteAsync Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.PagedByteBuffer", in MoveToAsync Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingWriteStream", in DrainBufferAsync Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter", in  WriteResponseBodyAsync Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter", in WriteResponseBodyAsync Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+  <<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0>d", in MoveNext Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+  <<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0>d", in MoveNext Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0>d", in  MoveNext Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d", in  MoveNext Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware", in Invoke Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware", in Invoke Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in ThrowForNonSuccess Module "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter", in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification Module "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol+  <ProcessRequests>d__214`1", in MoveNext ``

I google this but I've not found anything helpful.

UPDATE:

After check more details. this project is a micro service for manage discount codes. in micro service I delete discount code successfully from its swaggerUI and get 204 status code. but when call from ApiGateway swaggerUI, throw exception with message:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (0 of 23).`
I think this exception cause to micro service exception because the pipeline can't complete.
I check the api gateway and there is no middleware to add content after call downstreams I'm using `Ocelate` for api gateway.

Comment: The 204 status code means No Content, why are you trying to add some?

Comment: Do you have some kind of middleware or filter that adds any content after?

Comment: @Haytam It's ok when calling from swagger ui.

Comment: @Haytam I don't have any middleware to add content

Comment: Change return NoContent();  to return Ok();

Comment: @Sergey When return OK() It's will no throw exception but I want to return 204.

Comment: Just it seems to me that it is not API but it is your HTTP client problem. If you want some help publish your client code calling the API.

Comment: @Sergey I don't access to client source code, but exception says It's from swaggerUI and Kestrel, what you think about what happens in client side that cause to this exception?

Comment: I think it is trying deserilize content of the request if is not NotFound.

Comment: @Sergey I will ask about this issue from frontend team.

Comment: You are doing a DELETE,  Did you check to see if item is in database before trying to delete?  I think you are trying to delete an object that is not in the database.

Comment: @jdweng As you can see if entity was not exist I return NotFound(404).

Comment: The error 404 means the URL was not found.  I'm saying the query results does not exist.

Comment: @jdweng Item deleted successfully  from database but throw exception in pipeline when return NoContent.

Comment: You have to handle the NoContent outside the DeleteAsync.  Your code will only get a NoContent if you get a Content.

Comment: @jdweng I updated the question with new aspects. Any idea?

Comment: Your request is a Post which means it contains a header and a body.  The Content Length is the number of bytes in the body and is part of the header.  So the response coming back is really an error due to your request be malformed.   You have a content length of 23 bytes in the header but do not have any bytes in the body.  You are using html which has to be text (not binary) in the body or a mime attachment.  So if you are sending binary in the body that could be the reason for the error.  Usually you send a base 64 stream when you have binary or use GZIP.

Comment: @jdweng http method is ``DELETE``

Comment: In your request you have to specify the items that is being deleted.  So you are sending a  Post and the body indicates the type of query you are doing (delete) and the id of the item you are deleting.  The error indicates the body contain zero bytes but you are putting in the request that the content length is 23 bytes.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer for this issue?